# phonegap inappbrowser https pages not loading

Tags: cordova, https

Using phonegap 3.5 on a Android Gingerbread phone I've noticed that https links do not work

example:

```
window.open("http://google.com", "_blank", "location=yes")
```

works fine, but

```
window.open("https://google.com", "_blank", "location=yes")
```

just opens a blank screen. Has any anyone else run into this, and what workarounds might there be? The reason why I need to do this is for FB auth redirects which

Comment: Just out of curiosity, if you use `https://www.google.com` (with the www), does it work?

Comment: yes, why it will not ?

Comment: That works for https://www.google.com, but unfortunately not for many sites. Digging in a bit more Android 2.3 has some ssl certificate problems. More looking for a way to get the inAppBrowser to ignore errors.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to your MainActivity file

```
    public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view,
                SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
        Log.e("Error", "Received SSL error"+ error.toString());
        handler.proceed();
    }
```

This will do the wonder.

Comment: I haven't been able to get this to work. I don't have a MainActivity file, I have a CordovaActivity file that I tried this in. I also tried just replacing the existing onReceiveSslError with this code and nothing different happened. Is there anything else I need to be doing as well?