# How Bypass Invalid SSL Link in InAppBrowser Cordova

Tags: cordova, ssl, ionic-framework, inappbrowser

I face a strange problem. I try to open a link in InAppbrowser it opens a blank page look like:

[image]

And it doesn't show any error. But when I try to open  the same link in phone chrome browser it show me a message "Your Connection is not private" Look like: 
[image]

. I try by bypassing this problem by using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27238298/2143446), but not get success. Please Help me

Cordova install version: 6.4.0

Answer (score 5):

If this is Still open, then try this:  (i tried it today)

In file "**plugins\cordova-plugin-inappbrowser\src\android\InAppBrowser.java**":

1. Add this lines to import section:

> import android.net.http.SslError;
>       import android.webkit.SslErrorHandler;

2. Add this lines ( i added this below: onReceivedError() )

> @Override
>
> ```
> public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler,
> SslError error) {
>
> handler.proceed();
>
> return;
>
> }
> ```

3. Save your File

In Console of Project Root: execute

```
$ cordova platform remove android

$ cordova platform add android
```

and it should be good to go.

Comment: I wish all the problems I've encountered working on this app were resolved as quickly as this one. Thanks!